# How did Lagrange get his equation (the so-called Euler-Lagrange equation)

Tags: physics

The variational principle is named after Hamilton, instead of Lagrange.

So it seems that he did not derive his equation by the variational method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [who was the first to discover the Hamilton principle of classical physics?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5896/who-was-the-first-to-discover-the-hamilton-principle-of-classical-physics)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler This question appears to be a "how" question, not a "who" question.

Comment: @Geremia The other question asks “what exactly, was Lagrange’s role?”, and this is thoroughly answered in the quoted paper of [Fraser](http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~cfraser/Offprints.htm) ([1983](//www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=721716), p. 217); also ([1985](//www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=785432), p. 173), where $\frac d{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial\dot q_i}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_i}$ is traced to 1764, 24 years before the Mécanique Analytique. (Your answer would fit there just as well.)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Yes, Euler can claim priority over Lagrange in its derivation. (In fact, [Santilli 1978](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4395) p. 10 cites Euler 1736.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lagrange derived it in his [*Méchanique Analytique*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4321). Dugas summarizes it in his [*History of Mechanics*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4429) pp. 342-344:
[image: Dugas p. 342]
[image: Dugas p. 343]
[image: Dugas p. 344]